# Laravel and custom editor form macro

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-form

Is it possible to have javascript on a laravel form macro? I am trying to extend laravel to have a custom editor (like tinymce or ckeditor) but all the examples I see so far are to create the html portion of the editor and not add javascript capabilities.

I am thinking on creating something that would also run the required javascript portion of the textarea hijacking, so there would be instances. For example I might want 3 textareas with editor:

```
{{ Form::myeditor(...); }}
<br/>
{{ Form::myeditor(...); }}
<br/>
{{ Form::myeditor(...); }}
<br/>
```

and it would generate three editors on the same page.

Comment: Ofcourse that is possible, you can always load javascript in your body. Although it is not ideal.

Comment: I am looking for a more functional way, like loading the js once the editor macro is loaded, since it is part of the macro functionality. Any ideas?